# My problem is with this code. I get ERROR Error: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent -> AuthService]:

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, angular7

In screenshot i put my code.I am using angular 7.In my solution i used a HttpClient , i also put it in to providers array. I can't figured it out what is the problem. I 've read that maybe problem is  with rxjs but i dont know how to resolve that.

Thanks in advance.

[image: code snippets]

Comment: Please add your code as a code snippet here rather than attaching it as a screenshot

Comment: Did you import `import { HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http` and your `authService` and add them to your `imports[]` array  in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: I think it's a rare occasion where a screenshot is actually more helpful to provide a response. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your AuthService has errors (see squigly line under `options` and `user.tokenString`). Therefore it doesn't compile. The error is from `HeaderComponent` where you try to inject the service and can't. So first fix the errors in the service itself (hover over the errors; you will probably see that user is undefined) before injecting it into component